# UICollectionViewCell Talking to Its UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, uicollectionviewcell

Albeit potentially subjective, I was wondering how to go about having a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that when its `UIButton` is pressed, informs a custom `UICollectionViewController` of what to do.

My first thought was use a `delegate` in the `CustomCell` as follows:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    static let reuseIdentifier = "CustomCell"

    @IBOutlet weak private var button: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }

    @objc private func toggleButton() {
        delegate?.didToggleButton()
    }

}
```

where the class protocol for `CustomCellDelegate` is defined as:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func didToggleButton()
}
```

The `UICollectionViewController` then implements the `didToggleButton` function and assigns itself as the `delegate` to each cell as follows:

```
class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, CustomCellDelegate {

    func didToggleButton() {
        // do some stuff and then update the cells accordingly ...
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { fatalError("Unexpected indexPath") }
        customCell.delegate = self
        return customCell
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to go about this, or is there another way to to communicate between a `UICollectionViewCell` and its parent controller?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps it is. Delegation is an orthodox method to achieve that which works very well. You could also use [**binding**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/149753/bond-tutorial-bindings-swift) for that matter.

Comment: @Nitish Thank you for your comments ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it's the right solution for sure.** Your custom cells are blind and they don't know anything about your controller. They only fire delegate methods.

**But, there is one more right solution and it's observation.** Somebody prefers delegation, somebody prefers observation. You can use `NotificationCenter` to post your notifications about touches happening in your cells and make your controller an observer which reacts to these notifications.

```
// inside your cell
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("ButtonPressed"), object: nil)

// inside your controller
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(someHandler), name: Notification.Name("ButtonPressed"), object: nil)
```

And your func `someHandler()` will handle the call when your controller (observer) catches posted events.

Also, there is **KVO**, but it's messy and isn't good for that particular case since you have multiple cells.

One more way to setup communication channel is **binding**. It can be both manually written or reactive (e.g., using ReactiveSwift).

For example, manual one:

```
// in your controller 
cell.pressHandler = {
    // do something
    ...
}

// in your cell
var pressHandler: (() -> Void)?

...

// when the button is pressed you execute that handler
pressHandler?()
```

Comment: I would never go for Notification Center in such a case. For one reason it is a one-many communication and for other, it leads to poor architecture.

Comment: Personally, I also think that delegation is better here and in my projects I always do delegation :)

Comment: I added one more option to the answer.

Comment: @Aleksandr-Honcharov Thank you both for your comments -- they clarified my concerns ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, delegation is optimal when a communication has to be done to only one object. In this case the parent `UICollectionViewController`

Other methods of communications are-

Notification: When we want to communicate multiple objects post a notification.

KVO: To know when a value/property has changed. But use carefully.

Comment: I would never go for Notification Center in such a case. For one reason it is a one-many communication and for other, it leads to poor architecture